# Localization doesn't work for ios8 but works for ios9 and ios10

Tags: ios, localization

I have an app with localization. I used `NSLocalizedString` for every string that is seen by user and have files that has translation for those languages.

[image]

Everything works fine for ios9 and ios10 but doesn't work for ios8.

Do you have any ideas why so? Please let me know if you need more info in comment I will edit the question. Thanks!

**EDIT**: answering the comment: nothing is translated. none of the strings. don't mind about quantity of files. ios 8 - nothing is translated. ios9 and 10 - everything is transalted

**EDIT 2**: answering next comment:

I'm calling this method:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Оценки пользователей", @"экран Машина (машина найдена), название секции с лайками");
```

File with strings: 
[image]

note: all the strings are not translated only for ios8 (the string that i'm pointing is just an example).

compiler doesn't show any warnings :( though. which of the words should I look for in the console?

i set iphone language = english and region = usa

hope it's clear now! thanks:)

Comment: We definitely need more info. What, specifically, isn't working about iOS 8? I notice that only 3 files are localized for Russian and 1 is localized for Ukranian. Is the strings that aren't working located in a different file?

Comment: @keithbhunter nothing is translated. none of the strings. don't mind about quantity of files. ios 8 - nothing is translated. ios9 and 10 - everything is transalted. hope it's clear. thanks

Comment: Which one of the `NSLocalizedString` methods are you calling? Can we see the usage of one that isn't working? Can we also see the file that string is in? Are there any warnings from the Xcode compiler? What locale is your device set in when you are doing this? We need a lot more info than what we have to try to help you.

Comment: @keithbhunter thanks a lot for asking additional questions. i have edited the post answering your comments! thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on. You can try comparing the unicode values of the key in `NSLocalizedString` and the key in `Localizable.strings`; look for any differences there. That's just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **SOLVED** the issue. It is simulator ios8 bug. ios8 device works fine.

The way to switch localization for ios8 (if it doesn't work) is:
go to `Edit Sheme...` > `Run` (left pane) > `Options` (top tab) > Change `Application Language` to the one needed